# Optimization for Matrix Multiply (OpenMP) - C

Tags: c, matrix, openmp

I am learning a little bit about openMP and trying to use it here to multiply two matrices together.

```
void matrix_multiply(matrix *A, matrix *B, matrix *C) {

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for 
        for(int i = 0; i < A->dim.rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < B->dim.cols; j++) {
                C->data[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < A->dim.cols; k++) {
                C->data[i][j] += A->data[i][k] * B->data[k][j];
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

typedef struct shape {
    int rows;
    int cols;
} shape;

typedef struct matrix {
    shape dim;
    float** data;
} matrix;
```

Still a little new to this, so are there any simple changes to improve performance or have I already done that? Also am I running into any data races by not using reduction?

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation can probably not be improved a lot. At this point it comes down to the compiler and cache usage. An interesting point is made [here by Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/matrix-multiplication-performance-and-scalability-in-openmp-student-challenge/) that GCC requires two loops to be swapped in order to vectorize the multiplications (i.e. use SIMD). For very large matrices, you might consider dividing the matrices not in stripes but in blocks. This introduces complexity and overhead, but can improve cache usage.

The reduction clause is only needed if you are summing a single variable with multiple threads, which is not the case here since you only sum over `k`.

Finally (but this is completely personal) note that you can replace the two directives by a single one

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

which in my opinion looks somewhat cleaner.

Comment: If this is a pedagogic exercise (i.e. learning how to use OpenMP), fine. If you want a high performance matrix multiply, stop now. Instead go and find libraries such as Intel MKL which have many more optimizations (such as cache-blocking). Indeed, It may be interesting for you to compare the performance of your naive parallelization with that of MKL...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you may be able to improve your performance (no guarantees):

1. Utilize SIMD, this now comes with OpenMP (check compiler availability - not all compilers offer SIMD). You could implement it like this:

```js
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < A->dim.rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < B->dim.cols; j++) {
        C->data[i][j] = 0;
        #pragma omp simd
        for (int k = 0; k < A->dim.cols; k++) {
        C->data[i][j] += A->data[i][k] * B->data[k][j];
       }
   }
}
```

2. Consider the impact of contiguous memory allocation and the impact it has on SIMD instructions and speed of access. Typically this makes SIMD operations "row fast" and "column slow". This may impact how you choose to allocate your memory.

**Note 1:** Please be careful when you use

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

please ensure that you utilize private variables (or the reduction clause) as appropriate to prevent race conditions:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:C->data[i][j])
```

**Note 2:** It is possible you should use the collapse clause this sometimes improves performance:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3)
```